# How do I disable one tab in a QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I have a `QTabWidget` called tabWidget.  It has three tabs: "Basic", "Advanced", and "Current Structure". The tabs are displayed in the widget in that order.

I want to disable the "Advanced" tab whenever the Boolean `result` is false.  I thought it would be as simple as this code:

```
bool result = false;
if (result == false)
{
  tabWidget->widget(1)->setDisabled(true);
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not disable the tab, it remains enabled even when I check it:

```
tabWidget->tabBar()->isTabEnabled(1);  // This returns true
```

Why doesn't the tab become disabled? Is there another way to do it?

I am using Qt 5.4.0.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can enable/disable individual tabs in a QTabWidget using the member function [setTabEnabled(int index, bool enable)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setTabEnabled).

Based on your code snippet, it would look like this:

```
bool result = false;
if (result == false)
{
  tabWidget->setTabEnabled(1, false);
}
```

Comment: Or more succinctly: `tabWidget->setTabEnabled(1, result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not this way.

You have to iterate through all the children in the Page and disable them.

Something like this:

```
QList<QWidget*> list = parentWidget->findChildren<QWidget*>() ;
foreach( QWidget* w, list ) {
   w->setEnabled( false ) ;
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed. It prevents change of tab contents, but retains visibility of the tab.

Answer (score -2):

If you use Qt Widgets Application template and Advanced tab's name is `tabAdvanced` (you can check the name in Object Inspector), this should work:

```
ui->tabAdvanced->setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: what is `tabAdvanced`?

Comment: should be the name of Advanced tab QWidget, which is the child of `tabWidget`, you can check the name in Object Inspector

Comment: The questioner only wants to disable a QTabBar tab, not the QTabWidget, so your code does not respond to the OP.

Comment: It's not QTabWidget, it's QWidget. The questioner accepted Daniel Hedberg's answer which seems to disable tabWidget's page, my code does the same but in different way.

Comment: If you realize your question does not work since you are assuming many things, it is not general, I recommend you read [answer], if you improve your answer I will remove the downvote.

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer (not a question) but still I don't understand you claim, I've started my answer from saying that my code is not the general case

Comment: Do you think it is practical and elegant to use the name of the widget? A better option would be to use the index of the tab.

Comment: In this exact case when we don't need to iterate tabs, yes I think using name makes the code more readable.

Answer (score -3):

You could disable the layout of the tab.

```
bool result = false;
if (result == false)
{
  tabWidget->widget(1)->layout()->setDisabled(true);
}
```